# How to set sessionStorage inside the function?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a hyperlink who saves the session informations about a person and get data back in another html page. For some reason my code doesn't running .

```js
function potato(){
  var i=0;
  var person = [];
  var hyperlink = [];
  hyperlink[0] = document.createElement("a");
  person[0]{
  money: 200
  };


  hyperlink[i].onclick = function (person) {
    sessionStorage.setItem("cash","person[i].money");
    window.location.assign("person.html");
  }
}
```

Comment: `person[0]{
  money: 200;
  };` isn't valid syntax.

Comment: see the error **`"message": "SyntaxError: unexpected token: '{'"`** - you'd have seen that in your browser **developer** tools console too

Comment: My mistake, after "200" doesn't have a ";", but without this doesn't work either

Comment: `person[0]  = { money: 200; };` you are missing equal to sign in this expression

Answer (score 0):

```
function potato(){
  var i=0;
  var person = [];
  var hyperlink = [];
  hyperlink[0] = document.createElement("a");
  person[0]={
  money: 200
  };


  hyperlink[i].onclick = function (person) {
    sessionStorage.setItem("cash","person[i].money");
    window.location.assign("person.html");
  }
}
```